# Convert InputStream to BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, inputstream, readline, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a text file line by line using InputStream from the assets directory in Android.

I want to convert the InputStream to a BufferedReader to be able to use the readLine().

I have the following code:

```
InputStream is;
is = myContext.getAssets().open ("file.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (is);
```

The third line drops the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
The constructor BufferedReader (InputStream) is undefinded.
```

What I'm trying to do in C++ would be something like:

```
StreamReader file;
file = File.OpenText ("file.txt");

line = file.ReadLine();
line = file.ReadLine();
...
```

What am I doing wrong or how should I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 316, accepted):

`BufferedReader` can't wrap an `InputStream` directly. It wraps another `Reader`. In this case you'd want to do something like:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Yes, wrapping an InputStream with an InputStreamReader, which is wrapped by a BufferedReader is a common "trick" to use the readLine() function.

Comment: I recommend:
`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`
added in Java 7

Comment: StandardCharsets don't work on API Level >19. @brcolow

Comment: I think you mean to say doesn't work unless API Level >= 19?

Comment: @brcolow StandardCharsets was added in API level 19. He means <19.

Comment: This is not working with Socket. There are a few gibberish characters at the start of the first line.

Answer (score 26):

A BufferedReader constructor takes a [reader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) as argument, not an InputStream. You should first create a Reader from your stream, like so:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

Preferrably, you also provide a Charset or character encoding name to the StreamReader constructor. Since a stream just provides bytes, converting these to text means the encoding must be known. If you don't specify it, the system default is assumed.

Answer (score 21):

```
InputStream is;
InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
```