# Java: How to package and access resources inside a runnable Jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java console applicaton with a resources folder. It works OK, but when I want to export my code to a runnable Jar file(with Eclipse), then the exported Jar can not find the files(they are in buildpath) and give a Filenotfound exception.

When I unzip the exported Jar file I can see the files are there in the root folder, so I guess something wrong with my code.

```
BufferedReader srcFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources/"+filename));
String line = srcFile.readLine();
```

I tried to use

```
URL url= ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filename);
filename=url.tostring();
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getResourceAsStream(String)` (docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) if you want to read in a resource on the classpath.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200187/convert-inputstream-to-bufferedreader