# How to use BufferedReader to read content in DataInputStream

Tags: java, sockets

I wrote a simple socket tutorial about sending/receive messages between client and server. I used DataOutputStream to write the string in stream but server couldn't read it if I used **BufferedReader**

If I use PrintWriter to write(client side), it works.

What's wrong here? Tks so much.

**1. Client:**

```java
    client = new Socket("localhost", 1982);
    DataOutputStream opStr = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

    //pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    //pw.println("Hello, is there anybody out there?");// Can be read by BufferedReader
    opStr.writeUTF("Hello, anyone there?");
    opStr.flush();// BufferedReader can't read it
```

**2. Server:**

```
        openServer();// port 1982
        while(true) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;

                // listen to connection.
                clientSocket = echoServer.accept();

                DataInputStream inStr = new DataInputStream(
                        clientSocket.getInputStream());

                //System.out.println("M1: Got msg " + inStr.readUTF());// It showed the content

                BufferedReader bfReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                System.out.println("got Messages: ");
                String strLine = "";
                // Don't show anything
                while ((strLine = bfReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think that the way you have written data will allow you to read the data in that way only... like buffered reader/writer... data reader/writer... See the line you have commented in the server above... instr.readUTF(); that's what i meant...

Comment: I found this: BufferedReader can't wrap an InputStream directly. It wraps another Reader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200187/convert-inputstream-to-bufferedreader. All i need is changing to new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"). Tks so much

Comment: @ducanhng No. That doesn't gve you a solution for reading `writeUTF()` output with `BufferedReader.` There isn't one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. If you use `writeUTF()` at one end, you have to use `readUTF()` at the other end.

You just have to decide which API you're going to use, instead of trying to mix and match them.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read the files as either text e.g. BufferedReader OR binary e.g. DataInputStream. So you can't use both.

### Server.java

```
public class Server 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DataInputStream inStr = null;
        String str;
        openServer();// port 1982
        while(true) 
        {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            // listen to connection.
            clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
            try
            {
                inStr = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                str = inStr.readUTF();
                System.out.print((String) str);
                System.out.flush(); 
            } 
            catch (IOException io) 
            {
                System.err.println("I/O error occurred: " + io);
            } 
            catch (Throwable anything) 
            {
                System.err.println("Exception caught !: " + anything);
            }
            finally 
            {
                if (inStr != null) 
                 {
                    try 
                    {
                        inStr.close();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException io) 
                    {
                      System.err.println("I/O error occurred: " + io);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```