# How to read a file with Java's BufferedReader vs InputStreamReader?

Tags: java, spring, inputstream, bufferedreader

Below I have the following code to read in a file and go through it line by line.. This is using java's BufferedReader class. That I am fine with.

```
String filename = "C:\\test.txt"
String line = null;

FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

try {
    while (((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) {

    //do the following....

   }

} catch (IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However I want to now start using InputStreamReader in Spring / Java. I have the below code written but I am unsure how I can step through my file line by line. Really confused over this part. Anyone have any ideas or know how this can be done?

```
String filepath= "C:\\test.txt" 
File filename= new File(filepath);

try {
    InputStream fileInputStream = new BOMInputStream(new fileInputStream(filename));

// now want to step through the file, line by line..

} catch (IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Any reason not to just use `new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert InputStream to BufferedReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200187/convert-inputstream-to-bufferedreader)

Comment: Side note: consider to use the NIO.2 File API.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can read your input file byte by byte using InputStreamReader.

```
    char[] chars = new char[100];
    try {
        InputStream inputStream       = new FileInputStream("C:\\test.txt");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");           
        inputStreamReader.read(chars);          
        System.out.println(new String(chars).trim());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out -

```
String filename = "C:\\test.txt"
String line = null;

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));

try {
    while (((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) {

    //do the following....

   }

} catch (IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt")))) {

        reader.lines().forEach(line -> {
            // do what you want with the line
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```